# Do I use both Search Console's Remove URLs Tool and Remove Outdated Content Tool after content removal on my site?

Tags: google-search-console

Google Search Console offers to use the [Remove URLs tool](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/1663419?hl=en) so you can temporarily block pages from Google Search results. It also has a [Remove outdated content tool](https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/6349986?hl=en) to remove content that is still available on Google after its removal from its origin domain.

Do I use both these tools after removing a specific HTML Document or Image from my website with these ressources?

Comment: You use neither unless 1. you have a bulk number of pages (100's) or 2. you think those pages are harming you. Otherwise, just let Google discover them that you have removed them. For the average webmaster, these tools ain't required.

Comment: I can't find a way to bulk these requests via GUI or API

Answer (score 1):

You can use both but Remove outdated content tool is the right way to go.

Remove URL tool - 
Temporarily removes URL from search results - 90 days.

Remove outdated content tool -
Removes URL from search results if the content is already deleted or has been modified

Comment: Does the "remove outdated content tool" work slower than the Remove URL tool? I don't see the point of having two different tools to basically achieve the same thing. 

My use case in mind is a potential violation of personal rights due to publishing photo material of people without their consent, hence removing this content from Google should be managed rather quickly. 
Do I need to use the "Remove URL tool" in this case first and the "Remove outdated content tool" later on?

Comment: Remove outdated content tool is the right way to go for your use case. Fast or not.

Comment: I don't want to be stubborn about this, but I'm still uncertain about the correct use of Search Console's tools: Do I need the Remove outdated content tools at all, if I remove all content in question from my website? The documentation is not particularly clear about when content is assumed to be outdated (If there is still no change after a day, week, month?).

Comment: Also, the documentation for images seems to object what is said in other parts of the docs (https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/35308?hl=en&ref_topic=1724262): "For quick removal
Use the Remove URLs tool. You should see results fairly quickly." For me this implies that I use the Removal tool for urgent cases

Comment: Yet, the official docs for the removal tool reads "Do not use the tool to clean up cruft, like old pages that 404. If you recently changed your site and now have some outdated URLs in the index, Google's crawlers will see this as we recrawl your URLs, and those pages will naturally drop out of our search results. There's no need to request an urgent update." Does this mean, however, that the removal tool should still be used in urgent cases? Because a potential law suite would be an urgent matter to me.